# Unable to get the manual mock work using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, enzyme

I am trying to do a manual mock and it's not working. My test file Comp.test.tsx is testing a component Comp.tsx . My Comp.tsx has actions imported from another file Comp.action.ts (named export). I am calling abc() method exported from Comp.action.ts on mount which return the API data.

Now, I am trying to mock all the functions inside Comp.action.ts so that I can use dummy data for testing. I created `__mocks__` folder at the same level as Comp.action.ts and put a file Comp.action.ts inside it. But the test isn't going to my mocked file, instead it goes to actual file for data fetching. I have tried multiple times to figure out the issue but no luck. What am I doing wrong here ?

`Comp.tsx`

```
import {abc} from '../../Comp.action.ts'

// on didmount
abc() // it calls the api and stores the result in redux store
```

`Comp.action.ts`

```
export const abc = () => {
    console.log('actual')
    return (dispatch:Dispatch<any>) => {
        dispatch({type: LOADING});
        networkCall("get", `/channels`, url)
        .then((res:any)=>{
            if(res.error && isEmpty(res.error)){
                dispatch({ type: SUCCESS, payload: {res: res}});
            }else{
                dispatch({ type: FAILED, payload: {error: res}});
            }
        }).catch((error)=>{
            if(error?.response?.data){
                dispatch({ type: FAILED, payload: {error: error.response.data}});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`__mocks__/Comp.action.ts`

```
jest.mock('../Comp.action.ts)

export const abc = () => {
    console.log('mocked')

//  return some dummy data
    return data
}
```

Finally my test file Comp.test.tsx

```
test('it should display whatsapp plans text', () => {
    const component = mount(
            <Comp />
    )
})
```

My understanding is it should get the dummy data from `__mocks__/Comp.action.ts` when abc() is called on didmount but it doesn't. How do I achieve this?

Comment: You're calling jest.mock in the wrong place - that goes in the test file, not the mock file.

Comment: I have tried there as well, still it doesn't work.

Comment: Please give a [mre], including the outputs, for when the jest.mock call is in the right place.